# how can I round a float point to the next 0.5 increase in C++?

Tags: c++

I used the function round(); but this function gives me the nearest integer.

this is what I have so far:
    x = 1.3;

```
round(x);
```

this would make x = 1 and I want to go to 1.5 or If 1.8 to go to 2.0. please help.

Comment: why not using simple if else?

Comment: Multiply by 2, round, then divide back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this:

```
round(x * 2.0) / 2.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want an increase to the next multiple of .5:

```
    x = ceil(x*2.0)/2.0;
```

Comment: Cool I have forgotten about the ceil() function, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get value rounded by 0.5, double the input value, then use round function, and devide by 2 at last.

C++ code:

```
answer = ( round(x*2) )/2;
```